# How to I count the number of times text in column A appears anywhere in column B

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I have 2 columns of data and want to count the number of times text in column A cells appears in column B cells.

Here's an example

```
column a:
apple,
pear,
peach,
plum,
grape,

column b:
apple pie,
cheeseburger,
peach jam,
green salad,
grape jelly
```

The answer here is 3 -- words from column A appear 3 times in column B (apple pie, peach jam, grape jelly).

How do I wrote a formula to execute this count?

Answer (score 1):

- Use wildcard `*` with `MATCH` to get matching row
- `COUNT` the number of matched rows

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(MATCH("*"&A2:A5&"*",B2:B5,0)))
  ```

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Brenda Consider accepting the answer by clicking correct on the left of my post

Answer (score 1):

for infinity try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNT(MATCH("*"&A:A&"*", B:B, 0))-COUNTBLANK(A:A))
```

[image: 0]

---

or shorter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH(B:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A)))))
```

[image: 0]